# Help on a convergent sequence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me show that the sequence $(n+2)/2n $ converges? we obviously can see that it converges to $1/2$.

I simply said that for $n\ge 1$, $\;0<(n+2)/2n < n/2n = 1/2$, but that would only work on series what am I missing here?

Comment: $\frac{n+2}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$ but $\frac{1}{n}$ goes to $0$

Answer (score 1):

The given sequence is monotonically decreasing and bounded below, and hence converges to it's infimum. You can verify that 1/2 is the infimum of the sequence. Each term of the sequence is (1/2)+(1/n), which gets closer and closer to 1/2 as n increases.